How to use mathematica for differential geometry
I would like to learn how to efficiently use mathematica for differential geometry and tensor analysis. I googled it and mostly found some old references to packages. I wonder if there is a good modern package/tool/ads that I should use. Any help would be highly appreciated.

Read this:  https://www.amazon.com/Differential-Geometry-Mathematica-Textbooks-Mathematics/dp/1584884487/ref=sr_1_1?crid=2G7RX2XKEAALH&dib=eyJ2IjoiMSJ9.bR_FnpmN7ViRGuHTXgvrByleVQwrTHA432GHzKg3JYR8Urzcc5-vGJvfZ8VnyitnDNQsVpVXOSD6GSsiAwNKbi6K4J6vB-gvFASsBVhh_377tyvTM45vCBc-Ld6tdmfWCFEuWg_JXtnG1VGt741OHgMi57qPELOB84TqKUcxLvRo9TzejnlZB-37tsd_pPBT9CoRHNSGeP5y_AJUKuT0iJFJiec252iNwU3SJmx_0jE.VdzRIUIIyi5ZrNaTc4xzGEKhMEO76NPS3Q_h0VDCnpk&dib_tag=se&keywords=differential+geometry+mathematica&qid=1723071847&sprefix=differential+geometry+mathematic%2Caps%2C179&sr=8-1
